# Сериализация в Json списка с разным типом. Unity3D

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, сериализация, десериализация

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать подобное:

Есть объект, который необходимо сохранить в json формате. 
В нем есть список:

```
public List<object> Params = new List<object>;
```

В нем могут быть строки и целые числа.

Необходимо, чтоб список в json имел такой вид:

```
{
   "Params" : [10, "Hello!", 1919929202, 101202200]
}
```

Ну и конечно, чтоб можно было назад прочесть в объект.

Пытался сделать через JsonUtility, все правильно сохраняет, а вот список не хочет. Он просто отсутствует на выходе.

Есть варианты?

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Я в своих C# проектах (будь то Unity, WPF, да даже web) использую JSON.NET, чего собственно советую и вам. Плагин находится в Asset Store, легко ставится и используется.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо! Работает!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: использовать JSON.NET